# The target server failed to respond - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i am running a load test using Jmeter 2.10 on a web application.

I have a HTTP sampler with View results tree listener and I am running behind corporate proxy.

When i run the thread group even with a single thread,

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:295)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Advice

Answer (score 14):

I faced  the same issue "target server failed to respond" and here is what I did:

1. In your JMETER test plan you must have added 'HTTP Request
   Defaults". Click on that and for the Implementation field select
   HttpClient4 option from the dropdown.
2. Save your test
3. Now in the apache jmeter's bin folder open  the file user.properties
   and make an entry towards the end of the file as follows:

   - `httpclient4.retrycount=1`
   - `hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters`
4. Now open the file hc.parameters with the same bin folder and make an
   entry

   - `http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true`
5. Save these files
6. Restart jmeter

The above steps helped me resolving the problem.

I got the solution from https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed

Comment: It's worth noting these were disabled by default on 2.10+ due to reasons described in the wiki.

Comment: Worked for me in jMeter 2.13 - my specific problem only happened on a page with a 302 redirect (even though other 302 pages worked OK).

Answer (score 1):

You need to "tell" JMeter to use your corporate proxy via command-line arguments:

As per [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) guide

```
    -H, --proxyHost <argument>
            Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
    -P, --proxyPort <argument>
            Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
    -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
            Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
    -u, --username <argument>
            Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
    -a, --password <argument>
```

So something like

```
jmeter -H 10.10.10.1 -P 3128
```

will tell JMeter to use 10.10.10.1:3128 as a proxy. Replace IP and port with the ones from your corporate network.

Comment: thanks.I tried.But still no luck.org.apache.http.client.protocol.      RequestProxyAuthentication: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))